# Строка из цифр в массив типа int

Tags: java, массивы, строки, java-8

Подскажите способ, как строку из цифр типа `String` разделить на отдельные числа, границами выступает ноль, пример:

```java
String num = "120760570";
```

Мне нужно и поместить их в `int[] num`, так `num[0]` присваивается число 12 из примера выше, `num[1]` - число 76 и т. д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```
int[] result = Stream.of(num.split("0"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Менее красивый способ, чем Дмитрия, но как вариант.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String num = "120760570";
    int c = 0;
    //Подсчитаем кол-во чисел
    for(int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++)
        if(num.charAt(i) == '0')
            ++c;
            
    int n = 0;
    int[] nums = new int[c];
    c = 0;
    //Собственно парсим числа
    for(int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++){
        if(num.charAt(i) == '0'){
            nums[c] = n;
            n = 0;
            c++;
        }
        else{
            n *= 10;
            n += num.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
        System.out.println(nums[i]);
}
```